# C# custom sorting. All Ns followed by ASC order

Tags: c#, sorting, infragistics, xamdatagrid

I am working on WPF application using Infragistics XamDataGrid. I have few columns that I need to sort to work like below.

I will have values like -1.00,N,1.73, N, -5.6, N, 7.. I need sort to be like below

Asc order

> N
>   N
>   -5.6
>   -1.00
>   1.73
>   7

Desc order

> 7
>   1.73
>   -1.00
>   -5.6
>   N
>   N

I just need custom sort like below. Unable to get what I need to put.

```
public class MyCustomSort : IComparer
{
    public int Compare(object x, object y)
    {
        if (x == null || y == null) return 1;

        string x1, y1;            
        x1 = x.ToString();
        y1 = y.ToString();

        if (x1 == "N" || y1 == "N") return 1;

        return x1.CompareTo(y1);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**
Thanks to **user2023861** . I will accept his answer after I finish my thorough testing. I changed my Compare code below. I am still testing and initial testing looks good. Please let me know your views on this.

```
public int Compare(object x, object y)
        {
            //put nulls first
            if (x == null) return 1;
            if (y == null) return -1;
            //put Ns second after nulls
            if (x.ToString() == "N") return -1;
            if (y.ToString() == "N") return 1;
            double doubleX;
            double doubleY;
            bool xParsed = Double.TryParse(x.ToString(), out doubleX);
            bool yParsed = Double.TryParse(y.ToString(), out doubleY);
            if(xParsed && yParsed)
            {
                // both X and Y are doubles
                return doubleX.CompareTo(doubleY);
            }

            return 1;
        }
```

I marked **user2023861** post below as answer since it took me into right direction. I changed my code as per above and testing so far looks good. I will update this if I encounter any issues.

Thanks all.

Comment: You have to compare the two objects with each other, not compare them both against "N".

Comment: Thanks. I am looking how to get All Ns together.

Comment: Please don't remove code just because it doesn't work, it makes you look like you didn't try at all. If the code worked, you wouldn't have asked the question

Comment: This becomes much easier if you create an object that represents the possible data. Having an untyped `object` that might contain text or might contain a number is bit messy.

Comment: See the posted answer. A comparison function is not that hard to write; just give it a little thought.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read about the return values of the Compare method here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icomparer.compare(v=vs.110).aspx  In summary, result < 0 means x is first, result == 0 means x == y, and result > 0 means y comes first.

For instance, this line:

```
if (x == null || y == null) return 1;
```

returns a result stating that `x` should come after `y` because the result is greater than zero.

What your algorithm is doing now is this:

```
if x or y is null, y comes first
if x or y is "N", y comes first
otherwise compare x as a string to y as a string and return that
```

Edit: here's your answer (make sure to test this plenty, I haven't tried it)

```
public class MyCustomSort : IComparer
{
    public int Compare(object x, object y)
    {
        //put nulls first
        if (x == null) return 1;
        if (y == null) return -1;

        string x1, y1;            
        x1 = x.ToString();
        y1 = y.ToString();

        //put Ns second after nulls
        if (x1 == "N") return -1;
        if (y1 == "N") return 1;

        return x.CompareTo(y); //assuming these are doubles
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I am looking how to get All Ns together.

Comment: @Ziggler, will your data contain Ns and numbers and nothing else?  And do you want Ns to appear before numbers when sorted ascending?

Comment: Yes.. it will have Ns and doube values only like 0.00, -7.65, 12.78 and so on.

Answer (score 2):

I tried below in quick console application and looks it works :

```
List<object> lst = new List<object> { "N", "N", -5.6, -1.00, 1.73, 7 };
            var result=
            lst.OrderByDescending(item =>
            {
                double val = 0;
                if (double.TryParse(item.ToString(), out val))
                {
                    return val;
                }
                return double.MaxValue; /*dummy number*/
            }).ToList();

 foreach(var i in result)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
            }
```

Below is screen shot when snippet executed by OrderBy and OrderbyDescending operator :

[image]

Comment: How about to use a `double.MaxValue` instead of magic constant `999999`?

Comment: I think should be fine. I just did it in first 5 mins..defineltly can be better organised.

Answer (score 1):

You `input` are maid from strings, doubles and ints. You can group values by type and then apply sorting. Try this code:

```
var input = new object[] {-1.00, "N", 1.73, "N", -5.6, "N", 7};

// get all strings
var allN = input.Where(n => n is string);

// now filter numerics
var ints = input.Where(x => x is double).Cast<double>();
var doubles = input.Where(x => x is int).Select(x => (double) (int) x);
```

After splitting `input` by types you can recombine it with this code:

```
var asc = allN.Concat(ints.Concat(doubles)
  .OrderBy(x => x).Cast<object>()).ToArray();
var desc = ints.Concat(doubles)
  .OrderByDescending(x => x).Cast<object>().Concat(allN).ToArray();
```